# Redirect TCP traffic from my dev server to my machine for debugging

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

I have to write a .NET application that will listen on a TCP port and process the data that comes in.

For testing and development of other dependent apps (ie most of the time), I would like the TCP traffic to go to a server at my work.

But to write and debug this application, I would like the data to come to my machine.

But switching the computer and port that this data is sent to is not a frictionless process.

Is there a way I can have the data go the server, but turn on a setting of some kind that will redirect the tcp traffic to my machine (for debugging).  Is there a third party app that will support this behavior?  (One that is not too expensive.)

Note: The server runs Windows Server 2008 R2 and my machine runs Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This url had the command I am looking for:

http://www.rickwargo.com/2011/01/08/port-forwarding-port-mapping-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

The command looks like this:

> > netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=12345 listenaddress=192.168.1.1 connectport=443 connectaddress=192.168.1.1